# How to integrate react material ui Link with react router Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have a navigation bar which i'm trying to fix. The issue is that the router only works when you type the route in the search bar. It doesn't reroutes when i click the tabs. Only the home button tab works but not the other

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
 import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import logo from '../assets/mainLogo2.png';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import useStyles from './NavigatorStyles';
import { Link as Nav, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../home/Home';
import AnimeList from '../animeList/AnimeList'
import NotFound from '../404/NotFound';

function Navigator() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar position="static" color="primary" className={classes.appBar}>
            <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                <Avatar src={logo} />
                <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.toolbarTitle}>Anime Search</Typography>
                <nav>
                    <Link component={Nav} to="/" variant="button" color="inherit" className={classes.link}>
                        Home 
                    </Link>
                    <Link compoent={Nav} to="/animeList" variant="button" color="inherit" className={classes.link}>
                        Anime List
                    </Link>

                </nav>

                <div className={classes.search}>
                    <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
                        <SearchIcon />
                    </div>
                    <InputBase
                        placeholder="Search…"
                        classes={{
                            root: classes.inputRoot,
                            input: classes.inputInput,
                        }}
                        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
                    />
                </div>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
                <Switch>
                    <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
                    <Route component={Home} path="/home" />
                    <Route component={AnimeList} path="/animeList" />
                    <Route component={NotFound} path="*" />
                </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navigator;
```

As you can see i changed the Link for the react router to Nav since both names interfered with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss one char at the compo`n`ent here:

```
<Link compoent={Nav} to="/animeList" variant="button" color="inherit" className={classes.link}>
```

and I high recommend read doc [composition link](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#link)